# Accessing variables in the parent class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I've been stumped on this problem for a few hours now, and I can't seem to find a solution. I have a class that extends a parent class, but I cannot seem to access the variables declared in the parent's constructor.

I [borrowed my inheritance technique](http://js-bits.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html). It simply uses an "extend" function to create the subclass:

```
//In functions.js
function extend(base, sub, methods) {
    sub.prototype = Object.create(sub.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
    sub.base = base.prototype;

    for(var name in methods) { sub.prototype[name] = methods[name]; }

    return sub;
}
```

I create a class called Stimulus that serves as a function:

```
//In classes.js
function Stimulus(module_id, unit_id, attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
    this.module_id = module_id;
    this.unit_id = unit_id;
    //create some other class variables based on this.attributes, this.module_id, and this.unit_id
}

Stimulus.prototype = {
    _getStimulus: function() { //retrieve from database }
    //other functions here
}
```

And finally I have the subclass. The technique I use to create it is also borrowed from the above link:

```
//In classes.js
ImageStimulus = (function() {
    var $this = function(module_id, unit_id, attributes) {
        $this.base.constructor.call(this, module_id, unit_id, attributes);
    };

    extend(Stimulus, $this, {
        initialize: function() {
            this.fixation_cross = this.attributes['Fixation Cross'] ? this.attributes['Fixation Cross'] : false;
            //do other stuff
        }
        //other functions here
    });

    return $this;
})();
```

It all seems straightforward enough. However, in my main script, when I try to run this, I create the object and then try to run the `initialize()` function and everything falls apart:

```
//In main.js
var stimulus_objects = [];

for(var i = 0; i < someLimit; i++) {
    //module_id is passed directly to this function
    var unit_id = //some source;
    var stimulus_attributes = //some source;

    stimulus_objects[i] = new ImageStimulus(module_id, unit_id, stimulus_attributes);
    stimulus_objects[i].initialize();
}
```

If I check the console I see that is says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fixation Cross' of undefined

And it corresponds to the line in ImageStimulus.initialize() where I try to call on `this.attributes['Fixation Cross']`.

It seems that something is going wrong in making `Stimulus` the prototype of `ImageStimulus`, because `ImageStimulus.initialize()` cannot access the `this.attributes` variables that is created in the constructor for the `Stimulus` class.

Does anybody else see the error?

I have a decent amount of OOP programming in Java, C++, and even PHP, but this is my first attempt at JavaScript OOP, and so I feel like I'm probably making some simple mistake.

## EDIT: Solved the problem... somehow.

So it seems there was a fairly trivial solution. The `Stimulus` function was never being called, and it should have been called on the line with `$this.base.constructor.call()`. In the `Stimulus.prototype` object I added `constructor: Stimulus` and now `Stimulus` is being called properly. It seems odd that I had to do that (shouldn't `Stimulus()` be it's own constructor?), but it works!

```
Stimulus.prototype = {
     constructor: Stimulus,
     _getStimulus: function() {...
```

Does anyone know why that occurred and why my fix worked? I'm trying to understand what I did.

Comment: `stimulus_attributes` is `undefined` therfore `attributes` is `undefined`.

Comment: I put a console log right before `new ImageStimulus` and `stimulus_attributes` looks exactly as it is expected to. I also logged it right after entering the `ImageStimulus` constructor function and it prints as expected. However, if I try to log it just inside the `Stimulus()` function, nothing prints out; that function isn't even being called. What's causing that, I wonder?

Comment: What if you `return extend(Stimulus, $this, ...` instead of `return $this;`? (Since the `extend` function returns the `sub`.)

Comment: The error states, "cannot read property 'fixation cross' of undefined." Therefore, the context of your keyword "this" is grabbing the wrong context. Hence why "this" doesn't have the property fixation_cross

Comment: It seems there are multiple problems. First, function Stimulus is never being called. Second, this within the Stimulus function refers to the global namespace (window). In order for "this" to refer to the object instance, and not the global namespace, new must be enforced. A pattern for doing so that I read some time ago in Javascript Patterns is to include these three lines at the top of any function that is intended to be an object. Thus, if it is invoked with new, fine, if not (the usual) then enforce: 

  if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
    return new arguments.callee();
  }

Comment: @JimSpeaker What do you mean that `this` within the `Stimulus` function refers to the global namespace?

Comment: @NickAnderegg When you replace the whole prototype you have to fix it's constructor or it will point to `Object`. This is also rather inefficient `for(var name in methods) { sub.prototype[name] = methods[name]; }` would be better to alias `sub.prototype` to `subProto` to save on property lookups. Finally, `$this` is rather confusing... just use `ImageStimulus = (function () { function ImageStimulus() { ... } })();`

Comment: @JimSpeaker That defensive programming pattern is rather distasteful IMO. It's better to enforce code quality using tools such as JSHint than cluttering the code. JSHint will tell you if you forgot the `new` keyword. Why not using `new` would be the usual for functions meant to be constructors? I'd rather say forgetting `new` is pretty rare.

Comment: @plalx It is indeed a defensive code pattern, and I rather like it. In my experience, which of course is different than yours, seeing folks use new in javascript is pretty rare. The pattern protects against that lazy coding style.

Comment: @NickAnderegg Set a breakpoint on a line in Stimulus and you'll see what I mean by examining this. It will refer to window, because new isn't being used.

Comment: @JimSpeaker It all comes down to personal preference at the end, but in this specific case it's done properly and `this` will refer to an instance of an `ImageStimulus`... `new ImageStimulus(module_id, unit_id, stimulus_attributes);` The fact that `Stimulus` is called with `.call(this, ...)` will make sure that `this` refers to the proper object.

Comment: @plalx You're right, he was properly using new. :)

Answer (score 1):

I get it. You're replacing the entire prototype, so it is killing the constructor. By setting the constructor explicitly, you are putting it back. The alternative is to set the prototype method directly rather than setting the entire prototype.

For this fiddle to be useful, bring up the console and set a break point before clicking Run.
http://jsfiddle.net/x2v7wv6j/

```
//In functions.js
function extend(base, sub, methods) {
    sub.prototype = Object.create(sub.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
    sub.base = base.prototype;

    for(var name in methods) { sub.prototype[name] = methods[name]; }

    return sub;
}

//In classes.js
function Stimulus(module_id, unit_id, attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
    this.module_id = module_id;
    this.unit_id = unit_id;
    //create some other class variables based on this.attributes, this.module_id, and this.unit_id
}

Stimulus.prototype._getStimulus = function() { //retrieve from database 
}
//other functions here

//In classes.js
ImageStimulus = (function() {
    var $this = function(module_id, unit_id, attributes) {
        $this.base.constructor.call(this, module_id, unit_id, attributes);
    };

    extend(Stimulus, $this, {
        initialize: function() {
            this.fixation_cross = this.attributes['Fixation Cross'] ? this.attributes['Fixation Cross'] : false;
            //do other stuff
        }
        //other functions here
    });

    return $this;
})();


var foo = function (module_id) {
    var stimulus_objects = [];

    var someLimit = 10;

    for(var i = 0; i < someLimit; i++) {
        //module_id is passed directly to this function
        var unit_id = "some source";//some source;
        var stimulus_attributes = "some source"; //some source;

        stimulus_objects[i] = new ImageStimulus(module_id, unit_id, stimulus_attributes);
        stimulus_objects[i].initialize();
    }
}

foo(1);
```